# how to compare columns in dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with different dimensions (i.e):

```
df1
      A    B     
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12
3     4    13
4     5    14

df2
      A    B     C
0     1    10    10
1     3    12    12
2     4    13    13
```

I know how to retrieve the elements that are existing in both dataframes :

```
dfnew = df1.loc[df1.set_index(list(df1.columns)).index.isin(df2.set_index(list(df2.columns)).index)]
```

On the other hand, what I want, retrieve only the names of the columns that are existing in both dataframes and storing them in a variable, such as this example :

```
a= [ A, B, C]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) if need only union of columns names:

```
df1.columns.union(df2.columns).tolist()
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

L = df1.columns.union(df2.columns).tolist()
print (L)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Faster solution with [`numpy.union1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html):

```
L = np.union1d(df1.columns, df2.columns).tolist()
print (L)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
#use set on df columns to get the intersections:
list(set(df1.columns).union(set(df2.columns)))
```

Comment: It works, but it takes only two columns and not the third

Comment: oh, right, I think you need a union of two sets. Just updated.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helps.